# Do I need to use mocks?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I have the function which handles a specific bot event from Slack. Generally speaking, user clicks a button then my server receives and handles payload of this button.

The question is how should I test it? Do I need to mock `make_admin` and `build_admins_message` and check that they were called or I need to test real implementations? For example, I can retrieve the user from the database and check that it is actually an admin and also check that build_admins_message returns a dictionary that I expect to receive.

```
@slack_interactions.on('admin_add')
def handle_admin_add(payload):
    team_id = payload['team']['id']
    user_id = payload['user']['id']
    action_value = payload['actions'][0]['selected_options'][0]['value']

    user = SlackUser.objects.find_by_ids(team_id, action_value)

    if user and not user.is_bot:
        user.make_admin()

    return build_admins_message(team_id, user_id)
```

Currently my tests look like this:

```
class TestAdminAddHandler(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        team = SlackTeam.objects.create(team_id='TEAMID')
        SlackUser.objects.create(team=team, user_id='USERID')
        SlackUser.objects.create(team=team, user_id='BOTID', is_bot=True)
        SlackUser.objects.create(
            team=team, user_id='ADMINID', is_bot_admin=True)

    def tearDown(self):
        SlackUser.objects.all().delete()
        SlackTeam.objects.all().delete()

    def test_wrong_callback(self):
        payload = {'callback_id': 'wrong_callback'}
        message = handle_admin_add(payload)
        self.assertIsNone(message)

    def test_has_no_user(self):
        payload = {
            'callback_id': 'admin_add',
            'team': {'id': 'TEAMID'},
            'user': {'id': 'ADMINID'},
            'actions': [{
                'selected_options': [{'value': 'BADID'}]
            }]
        }

        message = handle_admin_add(payload)

        user = SlackUser.objects.get(user_id='USERID')
        self.assertFalse(user.is_bot_admin)

        for att in message['attachments']:
            self.assertNotIn('BADID', att.get('title', ''))

    def test_user_is_bot(self):
        payload = {
            'callback_id': 'admin_add',
            'team': {'id': 'TEAMID'},
            'user': {'id': 'ADMINID'},
            'actions': [{
                'selected_options': [{'value': 'BOTID'}]
            }]
        }

        message = handle_admin_add(payload)
        user = SlackUser.objects.get(user_id='BOTID')
        self.assertFalse(user.is_bot_admin)

        for att in message['attachments']:
            self.assertNotIn('BOTID', att.get('title', ''))

    def test_add_admin(self):
        payload = {
            'callback_id': 'admin_add',
            'team': {'id': 'TEAMID'},
            'user': {'id': 'ADMINID'},
            'actions': [{
                'selected_options': [{'value': 'USERID'}]
            }]
        }

        message = handle_admin_add(payload)

        user = SlackUser.objects.filter(user_id='USERID').first()
        self.assertTrue(user.is_bot_admin)

        user_in_list = False
        for att in message['attachments']:
            if 'USERID' in att.get('title', ''):
                user_in_list = True

        self.assertTrue(user_in_list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is two-fold. First, you have to verify that your code would work correctly with a functioning Slack server - as you have deduced, mocks would be a good way to do this, because unit tests should be completely standalone. You can also write mocks to emulate the behaviour of an incorrectly-functioning server.

However, this leaves open the possibility that your mocks don't correctly emulate the behaviour of the Slack server, and therefore your code doesn't work in real life even though it passes unit testing. In order to do that you will need *integration* tests to verify (as your current test class appears to) that the code works correctly against a Slack server.

When creating mock objects you can even go as far as capturing network traffic from successful transactions and then using that content to generate mock responses by patching lower-level components to generate the appropriate network-level responses to avoid interaction with the server.  Since you don't often have the ability to modify production servers for testing convenience, mocking is often the simplest way to verify correct handling of unusual server responses. It all depends how far you want to go.

Unit tests should validate the function of a single component, and should not rely on any external services. Integration tests verify that the code functions correctly in conjunction with other components, and will normally be performed only when the individual components' integrity has been verified.

Testing is a very large subject, so I hope this answers your question.